# mirth connect: javascript inser xml in mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, xml, mirth

I am new to mirth, java script, mysql thing. 
I have set up a channel in mirth to read a text file and convert it to xml. it works fine.
I also tried to send the xml to a mysql database using database writer in another channel.

This is what the javascript code looks like

```
var dbConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver','jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.4:3306/mirth','root','');
var result = dbConn.executeUpdate('INSERT INTO jon (xml) values ('1234')');
dbConn.close();
```

The above code inserts a record in jon table with value of '1234'. but how can I send the xml which I have read through the source:channel reader to the database?
I have tried to repalce '1234' with ('+messageObject.getEncodedData()+) or rawdata or transformeddata. none of them worked. I get the folowing error:

```
ERROR (org.mule.impl.DefaultComponentExceptionStrategy:95) .... Wrapped com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><delimited><row><column1>1234</column1><co' at line 1 (1cf6717f-4818-4b18-acb2-3b93079f2e95#7) .....
```

my intention is to write the whole xml in one field, no parsing needed yet.
thank you for your patient.
janmohamamdi

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting makes it seem like this is a simple syntax issue. Forget Mirth for a second. In general, if you are inserting values into a character field in a db, you need single quotes around the value that you insert

```
INSERT INTO jon (xml) values ('1234') //single quotes around 1234
```

When you create a query in javascript in Mirth, you are basically replicating the same query that you would use in mysql--but you are building it as a string programatically. You basically build the following string and tell javascript to execute it:

```
"INSERT INTO jon (xml) values ('1234')" //single quotes around 1234
```

That means that if you have an XML mapped variable, you need to surround it by single quotes in the query string so that your DB knows the value you are trying to insert. Based on your error message, that seems to be the problem. If you post the actual code you are using to do the insert, I can check to see.

```
    var xmlVar = $('XmlVar');  //fill a variable
    var query = "INSERT INTO testMRN (sendingfacility) VALUES ('" + xmlVar + "')";  //notice the quotes around the variable 
    var update= dbConn.executeUpdate(query);
```